# How to implement intersect using where exists or not exists in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, intersection

My tables are:

```
customer(cid,name,city,state)
orders(oid,cid,date)
product(pid,productname,price)
lineitem(lid,pid,oid,number,totalprice)
```

I want to select products bought by all the customers of city 'X'.It means I need to intersect products bought by all the customers living in city 'X'

Example:If there are 3 customers c1,c2 and c3 my answer is c1.product(intersect)c2.product(intersect)c3.product

I want to implement this only using `where exists` or `where not exists` because I need to write the relational calculus for the same in which `where not in` or `where in` is not available.My partial query is this:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  product p,
  lineitem l,
  customer c1 
where 
  exists(
   select 
      * 
   from 
     customer c,
     orders o 
   where 
    o.cid=c.cid and 
    c.city='X' and 
    l.oid=o.oid and 
    l.pid=p.pid and 
    c1.cid=c.cid)
```

The above query gives me the pid,cid,oid,lid,totalprice,city,productname of all the customers living in city X.Now I need to figure out how to select the product common to all customers.

Note:

I cant use any of the aggregate functions because it's not available in relational calculus.I have a working query using aggregate functions and that is

```
select 
   p.productname 
from 
   product p, 
   orders s, 
   lineitem l, 
   customer c 
where 
   l.pid=p.pid and
   l.oid=s.oid and 
   c.cid=s.cid and 
   c.city='X' 
group by 
   p.productname 
having 
   count(distinct c.cid)=(select count(*) from customer c1 where c1.city='X')
```

It's ok if someone can convert the above query in `where exists` or `where not exists` form without `count` and `group by`.

I am sure that it can be done because I can do that in relational algebra and according to [Codd's theorom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem) tuple relational calculus and relational algebra are logically equivalent and any query expressed in one can be expressed in other.As both relational algebra and relational calculus do not support aggregate functions the query can be expressed in sql without aggregrate functions.

Comment: What you want is called Relational Division, NOT EXISTS is basically Codd's query, see https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from product p where not exists(
    select *
    from customer c
    where c.city = 'x'
      and not exists (
        select *
        from lineitem l
        where l.pid = p.pid
          and exists (
            select *
            from orders o
            where o.oid = l.oid
              and o.cid = c.cid
          )
    )
  )
```

Relation calculus:

```
{T| ∃pЄproduct (¬(∃cЄcustomer(c.city="Newark")^¬(∃lЄlineitem(l.pid=p.pid)^∃oЄorders(o.oid=l.oid^o.cid=c.cid))))}
```

Relation algebra:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer.

I created a sqlfiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2fb85/1, so you can try it.

The query is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT c.cid
    FROM customer c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT l.lid
        FROM lineitem l
        JOIN orders o ON o.oid = l.oid
        WHERE l.pid = p.pid
        AND o.cid = c.cid
    )
    AND c.city = 'X'
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT c.cid
    FROM customer c
    WHERE c.city = 'X' 
)
```

Comment: I think the second part of `AND EXISTS` is redundant. And nice job.

Comment: @Mehran I don't think the AND EXISTS is redundant, because otherwise, for example, every product that was never purchased would be selected

Comment: You can easily test this in the fiddle you've provided. I had suspected that too but believe me , it's not needed.

Comment: The first part of your query is saying: select all the products which you can not find any customer that did not buy that product. And I believe it's all that is needed.

Comment: Alright, this is obviously way simpler than mine. +1

Comment: @marcosh On second thought, this new query returns all the products if there's no customer in city! Because we are saying `if there's no customer who didn't buy it` and if there's no customer at all, then it surely there's no one who didn't buy! I'm sorry to say a `AND` condition is needed to make sure there exists some customer in the city.

Comment: @Mehran you're again right. I didn'y think enough why I added the second part of the query. It needs to be there. Thanks for your remarks

Comment: @marcosh But the sub-query you've just added is a little too much. It does not need to be correlated to `p.pid`. As a matter of fact, it needs no `JOIN`s at all. It just needs to make sure that there exists some customer in the city, that's all.

Comment: @Mehran I just reused my provious version, sorry. Now I will edit it to what hopefully would be the last and correct version

Comment: @marcosh Please check whether my answer is right or not.Don't worry I won't credits for that as I got it by editing yours.

Comment: @user1613360 your query seems fine to me. Just have a look at the commets above here to avoid to return all products if there are no customers in the city

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I've replaced my previous answer with this one that doesn't make use of `IN`. This one makes use of multiple levels of correlated subqueries:

```
select p.* 
from product p
where exists (
  select *
  from customer c
  where c.city = 'x'
    and exists (
      select *
      from lineitem l
      where l.pid = p.pid
        and exists (
          select *
          from orders o
          where o.oid = l.oid
            and o.cid = c.cid
        )
    )
)
  and not exists(
    select *
    from customer c
    where c.city = 'x'
      and not exists (
        select *
        from lineitem l
        where l.pid = p.pid
          and exists (
            select *
            from orders o
            where o.oid = l.oid
              and o.cid = c.cid
          )
    )
  )
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6f7f0/1).

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use where in and not in clause because I want to convert it into relational calculus where these are not available only where exist and where not exists are available.

Comment: Well, `exists` and `in` are quite similar in terms of implementation, so I'll see if I can figure out how to rewrite this using `exists` instead.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI-Sql lacks set theories [universal quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), you need to [use rewrite roles to get existential quantifier](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/wccce/program00/kawash/kawash.html):

```
∀ Universal quantifier (For all . . .)
∃ Existential quantifier (There exists . . .)
```

Example:

```
(∀c ∈ CUSTOMER)
⇔ /*Add double negation */
¬¬(∀c ∈ CUSTOMER)
⇔ /*Bring one negation into the quantification, quantifier changes */
¬(∃c ∈ CUSTOMER)
```

Sql translation:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT c.cid
  FROM customer c
  WHERE  c.city = 'X'
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT o.oid
    FROM orders o
    JOIN lineitem l ON l.oid = o.oid
    WHERE l.pid = p.pid
    AND o.cid = c.cid
  )
)
```

[Fiddle-Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2fb85/37)